# $f\in C_{0}^{\infty},~u\in L_{loc}^{1}\Rightarrow fu\in W_{0}^{2, 2}$?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $f\in C_{0}^{\infty}$ and $u\in L_{loc}^{1}$, is it then true that $fu\in W_{0}^{2, 2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true. Basically, since $u$ is not necessarily weakly differentiable, the product $fu$ won't have the regularity you are looking for. It is enough to think about any smooth function $f\in C^\infty_0$ satisfying $f(0)\neq 0$ and $
u(x)=\vert x\vert.
$ Then, $$
(fu)''=f''u+2f'u'+fu''
$$
But, $u''=2\delta\notin L^2$, where $\delta$ denotes the dirac delta distribution. Thus, since $f(0)\neq 0$ we deduce that $fu''\notin L^2 $, what implies that  $(fu)''\notin L^2$ and hence $fu\notin W^{2,2}$.

**Edit:** Of course, notice that $\vert x\vert \in L^1_{loc}$.

Comment: $u''=2\delta$, not $\delta$. How do you define $\delta^2$?

Comment: Thx you for pointing out the typo. Why would you need to define $\delta^2$? To check that $\delta$ does not belong to $L^2$?

Comment: Yes, that was my point, but I get it. In fact, $u'$ isn't weakly differentiable, so writing $u''$ is a bit odd.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be a bump function which takes the value $1$ on some open set $V$, and let $u$ be very irregular on $V$...